# strpos not working PHP

Tags: php

I'm attempting to use strpos to see if a HTTP_REFERER contains a certain URL ($referral), but for some reason the following code isn't working.  However, if I replace the variable $referral with a string of the same contents, it seems to work.  Can anyone tell me why, or what I'm over looking?

```
//$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = http://www.example.com/something/somefile.php

$referral = 'http://www.example.com/';
$server = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if(strpos($server,$referral) !== false)
{
  echo 'true';
}
else
{
  echo 'false';
}

//outputs 'false'
```

Comment: "if I replace the variable $referral" - but $referral is already a string, Did you mean $server?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the variable content you expect to find within your string?

Comment: Try to print `$server` on the same url where you are facing the error, you will notice the difference, why it is not returning true..

Comment: Remember that `HTTP_REFERER` depends on the browser, so your browser is not sending this header, if you do a `print_r($_SERVER)` you will see that `HTTP_REFERER` is not setted

Comment: Also if you want to check host name, why aren't you using `'HTTP_HOST'` ?

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I am sure it is being set, because upon echoing them previously to the strpos, they are identical.

Comment: @Coderanonymous I guess he wants to know if the user comes from his website or from outside. The fact, is that we can't trust `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` because it's not ever set by the browser (as said by Elias). But this won't solve the problem with the `strpos`. If a problem exist... Edit: Moreover, add an extra condition to check if the referer is set or not.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `$server` is not `http://www.example.com/something/somefile.php`.

When using:

```
$referral = 'http://www.example.com/';
$server = 'http://www.example.com/something/somefile.php';

if(strpos($server,$referral) !== false)
{
  echo 'true';
}
else
{
  echo 'false';
}
```

Output is `true`

Comment: OP stated that, if he assigned `$server` manually, his code _did_ work, so really, you're not telling anything hew

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem are right, don't understand the +1

Comment: "Perhaps ..." should be a comment, and you're just rephrasing the strange behavior

Answer (score 1):

How, and if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is set depends on the user agent. This value needn't be set, and even if it is, it's not reliable. Taken from [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> *'HTTP_REFERER'*
>   The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

That's, I think, what you're overlooking here.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I took that into consideration, but what I can't figure out, is if I echo out $server and $referral, they are identical, which means it in fact is being set, does it not?  Edit:  It's only after putting into the strpos that it returns false.

Comment: @user1129107: If they are identical, try `var_dump(strcmp($server, $referral));`, if they truly are equal, it should dump 0

Comment: Just tested this and it returned "0"

Comment: @user1129107: Did it return `0` when you tried it with `$server = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, or when you hard-coded the value of `$server`?

Comment: No, it actually returned 0 when $server = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], which is what is making no sense to me.  What's more, is when $referral matches $server completely (not hardcoded), the code executes as expected, producing "true".  It's having trouble figuring out that the shorter URL is in fact part of the longer URL.

Comment: I should add that when $referral == 'example', '.com' or any sub part of the URL (unless hard coded), it doesn't seem to work.  So if it is predetermined that $referral == 'example', it produces "false".  If I hard code that it == 'example', it produces "true"

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing domain without any path eg: http://www.example.com, then your script would return false since there is no backslash at the end. Also you may not be opening the site with www or having and ssl (https)

Could you please post var_dump($server) on the page it doesn't work?

Comment: this is all part of a JSONP request, so I can't really var_dump.  However, I can set a variable to be returned with its value, and the value it returns, as well as the value of $referral are identical.  (strcmp($server, $referral)) results in "0" as well, confirming they are the same?